# Convert date, time stamp to date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the data in the following format in varchar form. There are 48 million rows in this format

'2015-09-18 00:00:00.000'

and want to convert it to the following format
'2015-09-18'

Can anyone help me with the code in Oracle

Answer (score 1):

If your column has a timestamp type, you simply need to use [to_char](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm#SQLRF06129) to  format it properly:

```
with yourTable(yourDateColumn) as
(
    select to_timestamp('2015-09-18 00:00:00.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') from dual
)
select to_char(yourDateColumn, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
from yourTable
```

If your column is a string ( and storing dates in string fields is generally a very bad idea) with a fixed format, you simply need a [substr](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions196.htm#SQLRF06114):

```
with yourTable(yourStringColumn) as
(
    select '2015-09-18 00:00:00.000' from dual
)
select substr(yourStringColumn, 1, 10)
from yourTable
```